# How to functionally aggregate individual timestamps into time ranges

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, functional-programming, reduce

Apologies for the title, please edit if you can think of a better one!

I have recently started to try and use more map/filter/reduce operations in JavaScript, and I have a problem I am trying to solve and I want to know the best functional approach to do so!

I have a list of rows from a DB with a 'time' column.

```
{[x, y, 15:10, z], [x, y, 15:20, z], [x, y, 16:10, z]}
```

I want to take this data-set, and spit out a different data set that looks like:

```
[{timebox: "15:00-16:00", count: 2}, {timebox: "16:00-17:00", count: 1}]
```

I can think of ways to do this that include several operations (such as just writing several filter statements per 'time-box') however I am asking is there a clean, simple way to achieve this?

Comment: whoever voted this down - can I get a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation using reduce and filter. Not using a hash or map type object so the lookup on the aggregated array is being done in linear time.

```js
var x = [["x", "y", "15:10", "z"], ["x", "y", "15:20", "z"], ["x", "y", "16:10", "z"]];

var y = x.reduce(function(e,i) {
          if (e.filter((n) => n.timebox == i[2].split(':')[0]+ ":00"+ "-" + (parseInt(i[2].split(':')[0])+1)+ ":00").length == 0)
           e.push({timebox: i[2].split(':')[0] + ":00" + "-" + (parseInt(i[2].split(':')[0])+1)+ ":00", count: 0});
            
          e.filter((n) => n.timebox == i[2].split(':')[0]+ ":00"+ "-" + (parseInt(i[2].split(':')[0])+1)+ ":00")[0].count += 1;
          return e;
          }
       ,
      []);
      
      
      alert(JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: Readability aside - this is exactly the kind of approach I was looking for! Awesome

Comment: shamefully I don't use to much javascript FP in my day to day for precisely that reason. I can't seem to make it readable while strictly sticking to the paradigm. I'm not a fan of mixing the two because at that point I'd rather take the traditional approach. These functions are really only great for simpler transformations IMO

Comment: funnily enough - I will probably NOT use this solution for readability purposes, but it DOES answer my question so green tick for you sir

Comment: Thank you, just out of curiosity - is it possible for you to do this aggregation on the db server?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the time and take only the hour part for a hash object.

```js
function getTimebox(t) {
    return [t, (+t + 1) % 24].map(v => ('00' + v).slice(-2) + ':00').join('-');
}

var array = [['x', 'y', '15:10', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '15:20', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '16:10', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '23:23', 'z']],
    result = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var timebox = a[2].split(':')[0];
            if (!hash[timebox]) {
                hash[timebox] = { timebox: getTimebox(timebox), count: 0 };
                r.push(hash[timebox]);
            }
            hash[timebox].count++;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A bit more compact style with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var getT = t => [t, (+t + 1) % 24].map(v => ('00' + v).slice(-2) + ':00').join('-'),
    array = [['x', 'y', '15:10', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '15:20', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '16:10', 'z'], ['x', 'y', '23:23', 'z']],
    result = array.reduce(
        (map => (r, a) => 
            (t =>
                (!map.has(t) && map.set(t, r[r.push({ timebox: getT(t), count: 0 }) - 1]), map.get(t).count++, r)
            )(a[2].split(':')[0])
        )(new Map), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var rows = [
  ['x', 'y', '15:10', 'z'], 
  ['x', 'y', '15:20', 'z'], 
  ['x', 'y', '16:10', 'z']
];

var sets = rows.reduce(function(set, row) {
  var currTime = +row[2].split(':')[0] + (+row[2].split(':')[1])/24;
  var key = Math.floor(currTime) + '-' + Math.ceil(currTime);
  set[key] = set[key] || [];
  set[key].push(row);
  return set;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(sets).map(function(key) {
  return {
    'timebox' : key,
    'count' : sets[key].length
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Basically this categorises the rows in different time intervals stored in `sets` and then creates the required result array from this.

Comment: I had to change the currTime variable as it was causing some strange behaviour - but as it stands since I am always using a timebox of 1 hour for now, the key can actually just be the floor of the hour.

I went for 'var currTime = row["time"].split(':')[0];'
'var key = currTime + ":00";'

Works perfectly though, thanks!

Comment: @aspiring_expert Glad I could help. :)

Comment: I still can't help but think there is still a simpler and smarter way of trying to achieve this goal. Perhaps it doesn't exist - but I am appreciative for this answer regardless!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to Underscore's `countBy` ([docs](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy))

```
_.countBy(
    (row) => { return getInterval(row[2]); }
);
```

Here, `getInterval` should return a time interval for specified time value (you can implement it for example with `Math.floor`).
It will produce an object like this:

```
{
    "15:00-16:00": 2,
    "16:00-17:00": 1
}
```

From here, it should be simple to transform to an array.